# How can I save something in one page and link to a new one and display data?

Tags: ember.js

Not using a data store... besides FixtureAdapter.

On one page I have an input:

```
    {{input type="text" id="form-name" value=personName placeholder="What's your name?"}}
```

I then go to the next page by clicking this:

```
    {{#link-to 'lets-design' class='btn btn-primary'}}Let's design!{{/link-to}}
```

How would I save that value of personName so on the next page I can display it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What matters in Ember is that there is only one copy of personName.  The one displayed on the first is the same as the second.  You must think in terms of your `Route`, which is the connection to what data is available on a given page.  [Read this](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/) for how best to use routes to control access to data.

```
App= Ember.Application.create();
App.set('name', 'Steve');
```

then in any page:

```
{{App.name}}
```

In your case, your binding to personName could be to App.personName, but that is not a very good general-purpose way of doing it.  Use this sparingly for special stuff that doesn't get stored on the server.  Most data is bound to your templates via routes.

Comment: Additionally saving global items like this on the application controller is common practice to avoid clashing with Ember accidentally.

Comment: Hey this worked with a straight string but how do I get the value from the form? I'm trying this: https://gist.github.com/ecl1pse/51950ede25975eadf463 but it says personName is not defined.

Comment: Add the "personName" property to your controller, like in this GIST: https://gist.github.com/shhQuiet/07ec45c9239fec0ebebd